# How can I split Multipage pdf file into muliple pdf files in ruby

Tags: prawn, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-2.4

I would like to know is there any ruby gem or script to convert multipage pdf file into individual pdf files per pages in ruby. I tried with gems pdf-reader and prawn but not able to solve the problem. Help will be heartly appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line utility [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) can do this easily

```
pdftk source.pdf cat 1-10 output first10.pdf
pdftk source.pdf cat 10-end output rest.pdf
```

or

```
pdftk source.pdf burst 
# By default, the output files are named pg_0001.pdf, pg_0002.pdf, etc.
```

Build a utility method something like this:

```
def split_pdf(source_file, dest_dir)
  Dir.mkdir(dest_dir.to_s)
  exec("pdftk #{source_file} burst output #{dest_dir}/p%02d.pdf")
  Dir.entries(dest_dir.to_s)
    .select { |e| e.ends_with?('.pdf') }
    .map { |f| "#{dest_dir}/#{f} }
end
```

and call it something like this:

```
source_file = Rails.root.join('public', 'source.pdf')
dest_dir = Rails.root.join('public', 'docs', doc_id)
page_files = split_pdf(source_file, dest_dir)
```